# IMA SDK integration for Android app, with videoview and MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, video-ads

I am integrating IMA SDK in my Android app, for pre-roll video ads in Videos. I am following the Google tutorial and the sample app provided in the link: https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/quickstart

In the sample app, VideoPlayer interface is used in conjunction with VideoAdPlayer from SDK. In our code we are using VideoView in a fragment for playing the videos, along with media player.

Since the illustartion in sample app is different than what has been done in our app, proceeding with intergaration is being little challenging.

Can someone give me details on how to integrate IMA SDK, with VideoView and MediaPlayer, and is it possible to pass only the AdUiContainer while requesting the Ad and not include any VideoPlayer instance?

Any suggestion would be a great help, thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/quickstart#prerequisites Kindly Refer this

Comment: Have you integrated this @Venus ?